# value for serialVersionUID does it matter?

Tags: java, serialization

I am using the serialized classes in java and in those classes I need to specify the serialVersionUID with some long number to be initialized.
As a default it takes as

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Or else I can initialize the same with some other long number too, like as bellow:

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5561040348988016571L;
```

some very big number.

My question is: Does it really matter which value we initialize to serialVersionUID or not?

Comment: My question was not basically why we need serialVersionUID but instead, does it matter if we initialize it with 1L and 5561040348988016571L which is preferred one?

Comment: Read the link I gave you, and you'll understand. I'm surprised you care about the value it should have but don't care if a serialVersionUID should exist at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is does this really matters which value we initialize to serialVersionUID or it doesn't matter.

No, it doesn't matter, *unless* you already have existing serializations (e.g. files) that were made before you added this member. In that case you must use the value output by the `serialver` utility when run on the .class file *as it was when those serializations were made.*

Answer (score 0):

If your object state is not going to serialized, then it doesn't matter else you will have to generate serialVersionUID everytime class structure changes (u can use eclipse default UID generation policy).

Comment: No you won't. You should never change a `serialVersionUID.`

Comment: EJP. Do you mean to say even though my class structure changes i should continue with same serializeversionuid?